# Line integral $\int_{AB}y\,ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I need to calculate this line integral: $$\int_{AB}y\,ds$$ Where $AB$ is an arc defined by $\begin{cases}
 x=t \\ 
 y=\sqrt{t} 
\end{cases}$ with $t\in [1,2]$

I got $I=\int_1^2 t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}} \, dt$ and now I'm stuck with this integral. I tried substitution method but it's getting heavier. How to approach this?

Comment: Note that$$t\sqrt{1+\frac1{4t}}=\frac18\sqrt{\left(8t+1\right)^2-1}$$which implies that the substitution $$8t+1=\cosh{(\theta)}$$may work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_1^2t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}\ dt$$
$$=\int_1^2\sqrt{t^2+\frac{t^2}{4t}}\ dt$$
$$=\int_1^2\sqrt{t^2+\frac{t}{4}}\ dt$$
$$=\int_1^2\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{1}{8}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2}\ d\left(t+\frac18\right)$$
using standard result, $\int \sqrt{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac12\left(x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-a^2\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}|\right)$,
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(t+\frac18\right)\sqrt{t^2+\frac t4}-\frac{1}{64}\ln\left|t+\frac18+\sqrt{t^2+\frac t4}\right|\right)_1^2$$
$$=\frac{51\sqrt2-9\sqrt5}{32}-\frac{1}{128}\ln\left(153+108\sqrt2-68\sqrt5-48\sqrt{10}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I don't understand what $d(t+1/8)$ means  after you complete the square.

Comment: well $t+\frac18$ can be taken as new variable say $u$  then $d(t+\frac18)=du$

Comment: I understood.Thank you!

Comment: It should be $\int_1^2\sqrt t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}\ dt$

Comment: OK, OP is stuck with $\int_1^2t\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4t}}dt$ please take a look at the integral asked by OP

Comment: Yes I noticed that. @HarishChandraRajpoot